# Twitter Digits method ‘lookupContactMatches’ not returning any matches

Tags: twitter, twitter-digits

I am using Twitter Digits and have 3 iPhones that are authenticating correctly and uploading contact books successfully.

However, `lookupContactMatchesWithCursor` keeps displaying an empty array, despite all 3 phones having each other as contacts.  There are no error messages.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Android. Before calling startContactsUpload, try deleting previous contact uploads using deleteAllUploadedContacts. The aforementioned methods are Android APIs but I'm sure there are equivalents for iOS. Also, I think that there's a quota limit per day.

```
Digits.getInstance().getContactsClient().deleteAllUploadedContacts(new ContactsCallback<Response>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<Response> result) {
            Digits.getInstance().getContactsClient().startContactsUpload();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Digits.getInstance().getContactsClient().startContactsUpload();
        }
    });
```